# Invalid syntax on single quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm working on a text adventure game and wanted to play a sound when you get a game over. I'm using PyGame to do this but it gives me an invalid syntax error on the last single quote when I try to load the sound file. here is the code:

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096)
pygame.init()
snd_dir = path.join(path.dirname (_Dog-Walking-Simulator_) 'Game_Over_Yeah.wav')
```

Comment: There is a comma missing: `path.join(path.dirname(_Dog-Walking-Simulator_), 'Game_Over_Yeah.wav')`

Comment: Also, `Dog-Walking-Simulator` isn't a valid variable name because of the dashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple things wrong,

- `_Dog-Walking-Simulator_` is not a valid variable name (dashes aren't allowed). But even if it were a valid variable name, it's not defined. Perhaps you meant `__file__`?
- `path` is not imported: `from os import path` needs to be added to the imports at the top
- There's no comma separating the parameters passed to `path.join`: `path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'Game_Over_Yeah.wav')`